# Reduce feature count when polygonize in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm performing a polygonize to convert a raster to a vector. Is there an option to reduce the quantity of features that it picks up from the raster file, at the moment there is 12 million features. I have 12 of these to do then merge them which is too large and slow. I'm using QGIS with GRASS.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to reduce the raster through resampling then convert it to raster through polygonize. It works